# OpenLDAP mdb backend

Tags: openldap, lmdb

I try to setup an OpenLDAP Server with mdb backend. But neither the version from packet repository nor a self compiled version (to be shure that back_mdb is compiled into slapd) works for me.

Config database is accessible, log doesn't print any errors and the database file is created (data.mdb) - but my root (suffix) won't show up and isn't writeable.

A basic configuration suggested by the OpenLDAP administrator's guide won't help either.

My config:

```
include /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
pidfile /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
argsfile /var/run/openldap/slapd.args

database    mdb
maxsize     1073741824
suffix      "dc=directory,dc=local"
rootdn      "cn=admin,dc=directory,dc=local"
rootpw      "{SSHA}Lh2sewmXFDo+bwc0Vqy12Xwc61n9sQ5t"
directory   /var/lib/openldap/openldap-data
index   objectClass eq
access to dn.subtree="ou=contacts,dc=directory,dc=local" by self write by dn="cn=server,ou=people,dc=directory,dc=local" write by dn="cn=phone,ou=people,dc=directory,dc=local" read
access to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=directory,dc=local" write by anonymous auth by dn.subtree="ou=people,dc=directory,dc=local" read by * none


database config
rootdn "cn=admin,cn=config"
rootpw "{SSHA}Lh2sewmXFDo+bwc0Vqy12Xwc61n9sQ5t"
```

Comment: one can test the config with slaptest -f </path/to/slapd.conf> also `access to access to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=directory,dc=local"` is not needed since rootdn has access to everything anyway. Ups, just noticed that the question was asked 7 years ago :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the ldif to create my root dn on the localhost.

Create LDIF file:

```
dn: dc=directory,dc=local
dc: directory
o: directory.local
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
structuralObjectClass: organization
```

Add the LDIF file and recreate database index:

```
slappadd -b "dc=directory,dc=local" -v -l basedn.ldif
slapindex
```

Start the ldap daemon and there it is: my root dn.